# Can't use ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework, html-select, ion-select

I use ionic to create an android mobile application. But I have a problem with the `select`. 
On the site of ionic, it can be seen that in the documentation, you can use `<ion-select>`, but strangely, when I try to use it nothing happens. The result is not the one expected, because it has no effect. `<ion-select>` is not triggering..

So I am forced to use this for now:

```
<select ng-model="form.city">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option ng-repeat="c in city" ng-value="c.id">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

While I would like to have the same result as on the official website, with `<ion-select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="form.city">
  <ion-option *ngFor="c in city" value="{{c.id}}">
    {{c.name}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: After testing your code, the display is good, but nothing happens when you click on it

Comment: You need the selected value to be bind with the model? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it ^^

Comment: it should work if you are binding the correct model. Can you share the code of your controller. Does form.city exist in your controller?

Comment: Which version of angular uses you? ?
ion-select & [(ngModel)] is meant for Angular 2, not for Angular 1

Comment: @DaxDev Thanks for the clearification.. :) I'm using AngularJS.. ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Try This its working fine for me

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Users List</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="myUser" placeholder="Select your User">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" ng-value="user.id" >
          {{user.name}}
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```